# Is there any class that gives bonus feats and sneak attack progression?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, optimization, sneak-attack

I'm currently making an epic naztharune rakshasa villain that I want to be a Telflammar shadowlord.

I am only missing the 2d6 sneak attack damage necessary to get into that class, and I have 10-13 levels to work with. Most rogue and assassin class features are kinda useless to a naztharune rakshasa, so I am looking for another way to get the 2d6 sneak attack I need along with better class features. Bonus feats, especially feats that help entry into Telflammar shadowlord or improve two-weapon fighting, are particularly desirable.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! You might want to take a look at the [Tour], if you haven’t. Either way, I think you should be more specific: what sort of feats? how good a sneak attack progression? Because as-is, rogue qualifies since it can select a bonus feat (once) as a talent, and I don’t think that’s what you mean.

Comment: I'll go ahead and edit my question, but I am not looking at the rogue. I am currently looking for any kind of sneak attack progression above 2d6 within 10 class lvls, honestly any kind of feats would be nice but something towards two-weapon fighting would be ideal. Anything prestige would also be great.

Comment: I have edited your question to make it a little easier to read; please make sure I didn’t mess it up or change the question any.

Comment: Thank you, I am a bit of a mess right now so it is greatly appreciated. I feel as though you pretty much answered my question though with your list of classes. I just don't know if the one I am currently looking at now is the best choice though, but the Savant seems to be the best answer that I am looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Blade Bravo (*Races of Stone*, 10 levels, melee sneak attack on 4, 8, bonus feat on 3, 6, 9)
- Chameleon (*Races of Destiny*, 10 levels, 1d6 sneak attack 1/day on 3, 6, 9, floating bonus feat at 2)
- Crinti Shadow Marauder (*Shining South*, 5 levels, sudden strike on even levels, mounted feat at 3)
- Dragon Devotee (*Races of the Dragon*, 5 levels, choice of bonus feat or +1d6 bonus damage on even levels)
- Fang of Sseth (*Serpent Kingdoms*, 10 levels, sneak attack on 1, 4, 7, 10, archery feat at 2nd)
- Hand of the Winged Masters (*Dragon Magic*, 10 levels, sneak attack on 2, 5, 8, draconic feats at 1st and 3rd)
- Justice of Weald and Woe (*Champions of Ruin*, 10 levels, sneak attack at 3rd and 7th, bonus archery feats at 2nd and 8th)
- Knight of the Lily (*Dragonlance Campaign Setting*, 10 levels, sneak attack on 1, 4, 7, 10, Diehard at 3rd)
- Legacy Champion (*Weapons of Legacy*, 10 levels, progress existing sneak attack or bonus feats 8/10, bonus legacy item feats at 4 and 8)
- Outlaw of the Crimson Road (*Song & Silence*, 10 levels, “ambush” on odd levels, bonus feats at 2, 4, 5)
- Ronin (*Complete Warrior* 10 levels, sneak attack on 1, 4, 7, 10, archery or mounted feats at 5 and 9)
- Savant (*Dragon Compendium*, 20 levels, sneak attack at 3, 9, 15, bonus feats, apparently *any* feats, at 2, 7, 12, 17)
- Scarlet Corsair (*Stormwrack*, 10 levels, sneak attack on 2, 6, 10, Improved Feint on 1)
- Scorpion Heritor (*Sandstorm*, 10 levels, sneak attack at even levels, scorpion feats at 1 and 7)
- Shadow Thief of Amn (*Player’s Guide to Faerûn*, 5 levels, sneak attack at odd levels, bonus feat on even levels)
- Shadowbane Inquisitor (*Complete Adventurer*, 10 levels, sneak attack on 4, 7, 10, Improved Sunder on 3)
- Spellwarp Sniper (*Complete Scoundrel*, 5 levels, “sudden raystrike” on even levels, Precise Shot on 3)
- Thief-acrobat (*Song & Silence* version, 10 levels, sneak attack on 4 and 9, Improved Trip on 2)
- Twisted Lord (*The Shattered Gates of Slaughtergarde*, 10 levels, sneak attack on 2, 5, 8, Improved Feint on 3)
- Unseen Seer (*Complete Mage*, 10 levels, damage bonus on 1, 4, 7, 10, Still Spell on 2)

So far as I can tell, this is every class in the game save the rogue that grants any kind of sneak attack damage (plus some that give things like sneak attack) as well as at least one bonus feat of some kind. None of them seem to be really offering TWF feats, but blade bravo and shadow thief of Amn offer the feats that seem *most* useful to a dual-wielder. Chameleon also deserves a second look, just because that class is awesome, though not particularly for sneak attack.